# How can I display images that display for different times using setTimeout/setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, image, settimeout, setinterval

My goal is to display two images that last for 5 seconds each at the beginning, then images from a different folder will display for 3 seconds each. I currently display the images from the folder using set Interval and am trying to display the initial two images at the beginning using setTimeout. Right now when I run this, the page shows the code I have for the setInterval at the top of the page and the second image (`fun-src`) from my setTimeout blocks below. The `struc-src` image does not show at all. How can I align these two images with the rest of the images and make them appear only for 5 seconds and disappear after? I am new to javascript so I would appreciate any help with how to achieve this. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <section id="img-container"></section>

    <img id="Scan" struc-src="img1.png" fun-src="img2.png"/>    

    <script type="text/javascript">

    //my attempt to display the two pictures
    var scans = document.getElementById("Scan");
    var strucScan = scans.getAttribute("struc-src");
    var funScan = scans.getAttribute("fun-src");
    scans.src = structScan;
    scans.style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(() => {
        scans.style.display = "none";
        scans.src = funcScan;
        scans.style.display = "block";
    }, 5000);

    //everything below this line works
    const numOfPictures = 200;
    const picturesNumberLength = 3;
    let imageIndex = 1;
    let imagesArray = [];
    const imagesContainer = document.getElementById("img-container");

    for (let i = 1; i < numOfPictures + 1; i++) {
        const img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = `foldername/homeFolder_${(i+"").padStart(picturesNumberLength,"0")}.png`;
        img.classList.add("slides");
        img.style.width = "80%";
        img.style.display = "none";
        imagesContainer.appendChild(img);
        imagesArray.push(img);
    }
    imagesArray[0].style.display = "block";
    setInterval(() => {
        imagesArray[imageIndex].style.display = "block";
        if (imageIndex > 0) imagesArray[imageIndex-1].style.display = "none";
        else imagesArray[numOfPictures-1].style.display = "none";
        imageIndex++;
        if (imageIndex >= numOfPictures) imageIndex = 0;
    }, 3000);

    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: When you run this code, open the Developer Tools console and look for errors (pressing F12 opens Developer Tools in most browsers).

Comment: I'm not getting any errors after moving the html line above the script tag, right now the images with the setTimeout part and setInterval part are showing below and above each other respectively. If you have any ideas on how to show them one after another I would appreciate that

Comment: your setTimeouts run exactly at the same time

Comment: I changed it so that I only have a setTimeout for the fun-src image. Now the struc-src image shows, but the fun-src image does not leave. These two images also do not show before the images form setInterval - they both show at the same time. How can I make the setInterval images appear after those first two images have displayed?

Comment: I think you need to describe the states more clearly. I.e., what all do you expect to see at the 1 second mark? The 6 second mark?  Each 3-second interval, etc.?  Are images disappearing?  If so, which ones?

Comment: for the first 5 seconds - struc-src should display then disappear, the next 5 seconds, fun-src displays and disappears, after that the images I'm putting in the images array should display for 3 seconds each. Does make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an extra timeout.

0s: `scans.src = structScan;`

5s: `scans.src = funScan;`

10s: `scans.style.display = "none"; imagesArray[0].style.display = "block";`

```js
var scans = document.getElementById("Scan");
var structScan = scans.getAttribute("struc-src");
var funScan = scans.getAttribute("fun-src");
scans.src = structScan;
setTimeout(() => {
    scans.src = funScan;
}, 5000);

//everything below this line works
const numOfPictures = 5;
const picturesNumberLength = 3;
let imageIndex = 1;
let imagesArray = [];
const imagesContainer = document.getElementById("img-container");

for (let i = 1; i < numOfPictures + 1; i++) {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = `https://via.placeholder.com/150x150&text=home${(i+"").padStart(picturesNumberLength,"0")}.png`;
    img.classList.add("slides");
    img.style.display = "none";
    imagesContainer.appendChild(img);
    imagesArray.push(img);
}

setTimeout(() => {
    scans.style.display = "none";
    imagesArray[0].style.display = "block";
  
    setInterval(() => {
        imagesArray[imageIndex].style.display = "block";
        if (imageIndex > 0) imagesArray[imageIndex-1].style.display = "none";
        else imagesArray[numOfPictures-1].style.display = "none";
        imageIndex++;
        if (imageIndex >= numOfPictures) imageIndex = 0;
    }, 3000);
  
}, 10000);
```

```html
<section id="img-container"></section>

<img id="Scan" struc-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150&text=img1.png" fun-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150&text=img2.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move html outside of the script tag. You should add
`<img id="Scan" struc-src="img1.png" fun-src="img2.png"/>` underneath or within your section above.

Comment: When I do this, the images I want to show for 5 seconds  don't appear, just the ones I am implementing with the setInterval. Is there something wrong with how I am doing the setTimeout part?

Comment: Actually, the image specified by fun-src is showing below the images from the setInterval and does not disappear after 5 seconds. The struc-src image does not show at all. Is there a way I can align these two images from the images in setInterval?